# ¿Cómo desactivo o elimino el evento click del botón para iniciar otra función y así sumar un párrafo? ¿Por qué al iterar el array arroja undefined?

Tags: javascript, array, eventos, dom, click

¿De qué manera elimino o desactivo el evento click del botón para que inicie otra función y así sumar otro párrafo y la variable "products" se muestre de manera adecuada? ¿Por qué al iterar el array arroja undefined? ¿por qué no me guarda la info correctamente en el local storage?

```
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let title = document.getElementById("title");
let paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph");

button.addEventListener("click", startForm);

function startForm() {
    title.textContent = "Elige el producto que buscas.";
    paragraph.textContent = "Ingrese su nombre";
    
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.idName = "inputOne";

    let name = input.value;
    localStorage.setItem("Name", name);

    let container = document.getElementById("mainContent");
    container.appendChild(input);

    button.textContent = "Siguiente"; 

    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(newDiv);

    for(product of products) {
        newDiv.innerHTML += `
        <p>Tipo: ${products.name}</p>
        `
    }
}

var products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Remeras",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Leggins",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Buzos",
    }
]




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <title>Cotizador</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contacto</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="firstContainer" id="firstContainer">
            <div id="mainContent">
                <img src="img/indumentaria.png" alt="indumentaria">
                <h1 id="title">
                    Indumentaria deportiva de alta calidad
                </h1>
                <p id="paragraph">
                    Ingresá las características del producto que estás buscando, conocé su precio y confirmá tu pedido.
                </p>
            </div>
            <button id="button">Comenzar</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>
            Devjogger.
        </p>
    </footer>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Al iterar te lanza undefinded porque estás poniendo `<p>Tipo: ${products.name}</p>` con una s y debería ser `<p>Tipo: ${product.name}</p>`. Puedes eliminar el evento simplemente con [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

Comment: Considera adjuntar parte de tu html en este tipo de preguntas, así tu problema puede reproducirse de manera más fácil.

Comment: Tienes razón @JaimeMenéndez acabo de colocar el código HTML pues todavía no sé cómo eliminar o desactivar el evento click del botón para que inicie otra función y así sumar otro párrafo

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar el evento del botón:

```
button.removeEventListener("click", startForm);
```

- En el localStorage sí se guarda el atributo Name, pero su valor es vacío, ya que guardas inmediatamente después de crear el input.
- Podrías añadir un evento al input para que guarde el valor al introducir un valor.
- Además, si creas otro párrafo, lo que introduzcas sobre escribirá el localStorage atributo Name, deberías dar distintos nombres para almacenar los valores de cada input.

```
  let i = 0;
  function startForm() {
      title.textContent = "Elige el producto que buscas.";
      paragraph.textContent = "Ingrese su nombre";

      let input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
      input.idName = "input"+i;

      input.addEventListener('keyup', saveIntoLocalStorage);

      let container = document.getElementById("mainContent");
      container.appendChild(input);

      button.textContent = "Siguiente";

      let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      container.appendChild(newDiv);

      for(product of products) {
          newDiv.innerHTML += `
          <p>Tipo: ${product.name}</p>
          `
      }
      i++;
  }

  function saveIntoLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.setItem(this.idName, this.value);
  }
```